# specifying a different home activity at run-time

Tags: android

To specify my "Home" activity at compile-time, I can use the following code in my AndroidManifest.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".HomeActivity"
        <intent-filter android:label="@string/home_activity">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have a requirement though where I need to be able to specify the activity I would like to use as my "Home" screen at **"run-time".**  Does anyone know if this is possible?  Basically, I want to replace "HomeActivity" with something else.

I looked into using an "activity-alias" where I can specify the target activity using the "targetActivity" attribute but I didn't quite get how I can use this.

Thanks!

Comment: The easiest way would be to have the Activity just be a container for Fragments, and load a different Fragment at runtime depending on the situation.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  Based on what would you change it?  There's a simple way to do it (use a blank activity as the launcher who's onCreate launches the real activity then calls finish()), but there's very limited use for it-  you're probably missing something easier to do.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  I am currently using the blank activity approach where I then invoke startActivity but it creates a "flicker" effect.  I wanted to do this "dynamic" approach of setting the home screen in hopes that it would remove the "flicker" :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Jon you can conditionally call separate activity from splash.Like you have a condition that on first app launch you need to open a tutorial screen and then onwards your home Activity then you can create different intents.

```
 if (!sharedPreferences.contains(DiceConstants.FIRST_TIME_PREFS)) {
        intent = new Intent(this, TutorialActivity.class);
        sharedPreferences.edit().putBoolean(DiceConstants.FIRST_TIME_PREFS, true).commit();
    } else {
        intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't for a splash screen.

Comment: Yes it could be for any other screen